# Forcing HTTPS with .htaccess in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

My existing `.htaccess` removes `index.php` from my URLs perfectly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
ErrorDocument 404 /application/errors/404.php
</IfModule>
```

I need the entire site to run over SSL, and Pagoda Box, my hosting company, has a proprietary `.htaccess` edit to switch from `http` to `https`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} = http
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R]
```

It only works if added at the end of the first conditional statement, and it works perfectly at that: it adds `https` to a naked URL and removes `index.php`.

However, if you select the `s` from `https` in the address bar and delete it, `index.php` comes back, plus the last segment of the URL is repeated. If I type the full url, beginning with `http://`, it redirects and works perfectly - only if I place the cursor in front of the `s` and delete it does the site break.

Any ideas on how to stop this new condition and rule from conflicting with my existing file?

Comment: "only if I place the cursor in front of the "s" and delete it does the site break" <- that sounds impossible. The server has no way of knowing what you're doing with your browser's GUI. I believe it's a caching issue -- have you tried emptying the browser cache? Have you tried other browsers? Have you tried from other computers?

Comment: To whoever down-voted - I understand keeping the community in line, but that is extremely non-constructive if you don't say in the comments that you did it and give an explanation to help me correct my misdeed in the future.

Comment: I don't know why they (the hosting company) aren't using something sensible, like `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}`.

Comment: @netcoder - yes, they do.  Hiding index.php, which involves codeigniter route and config edits working in tandem with .htaccess edits, is what is conflicting with my https redirect.  If anyone else has this issue, it will probably be on codeigniter and the tag helps to make this findable.  I just blew a 10 hour workday on this issue.  I'm re-adding the tag.

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff they're explanation is on http://help.pagodabox.com/customer/portal/articles/175458-adding-ssl.  And yes, for the police, this comment is relevant as the link is to pagoda's explanation and htaccess edit recommendation.

Comment: @erquhart: well the least you can do is mention CI in your question and the explanation you just gave. Otherwise the tag has no value whatsoever. And there's no police, this community is built on valuable and organized content, and we like to keep it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any CI/Pagoda Box users, here's what worked for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteBase /

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|js|docs|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
ErrorDocument 404 /application/errors/404.php
</IfModule>
```

Notice that RewriteBase is after the https redirect, and the [L] to end processing.

Comment: @MikeBrant - no disrespect to your answer above.  I had already tried positioning the https rewrite at the top prior to your post, and it didn't work until I realized the caveat above.  I did take your '!https' idea though - it didn't affect the issue at hand, but it is more versatile.

Answer (score 3):

Try placing the http to https redirect as the first thing.  it is also probably best to use `!https` as the condition for the rewrite.  So the rewrite section of your .htaccess could look like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R]

#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|(.*)\.swf|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|cache)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Placing it first causes a strange, unresolvable redirect.  I could only get this to work by placing the two lines where they are in the OP.

Comment: three upvotes?  it really doesn't work for my case folks.  promise.

Answer (score 1):

My preference is to configure this type of redirect within the virtual host instead of using .htaccess

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName secure.example.com
   DocumentRoot /path_to_webroot/
   SSLEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```